Using Dijkstra algorithm to answer queries
I have to find an algorithm (I dont have to code it) to solve the task: given that $|E|-|V| \leq C$ ($C$ is natural constant)  in undirected connected nonnegative-weighted graph, and I need to answer the queries to find the length of shortest path between two vertices $u$, $w$ for $\mathcal{O}(1)$ and I can do preprocess for $\mathcal{O}(|E|\log(|V|))$ time.
My attempt: let $|V| = V_1+V_2$ - where $V_1$ is amount of vertices with degree $1$ and $V_2$ is amount of vertices with degree $\geq 2$. So I have $ C + |V| \geq |E| = sum_{degrees} \geq (2V_2 + V_1)/2$, but it leads nowhere because it's obviously true.. I feel like I need Dijkstra algorithm, but don't really see how to apply it to answering queries... please help...

I give here series of hints and then a complete solution.
Hint 1. Let $n = |V|$ and $m = |E|$. Firstly consider the case of minimum possible value $C = -1$. What can we say about such graph?
Hint 1a.

 It means that $m = n - 1$ and the given graph is a tree.

Let's select one arbitrary vertex and give it special status. What can we say about path between two vertices now?
Hint 1b.

 Selecting a vertex means dealing with a rooted tree. Note that the only path between two vertices in a rooted tree goes through their lower common ancestor (i. e. ancestor with maximum depth), or LCA, and doesn't go through any other common ancestors.

How to find path length in $\mathrm O(1)$ of time using such special object?
Hint 1c.

 If we precompute the distance $d(v)$ from root to every vertex $v \in V$ in $\mathrm O(n)$ of time the for given vertices $u$ and $v$ with lowest common ancestor $w$ (which may be one of $u$ and $v$ as well) the length of $(u, v)$-path is $d(u) - d(w) + d(v) - d(w)$.

How can we find this special object fast?
Hint 1d.

 Use constant-time lowest common ancestor queries.

Ok, let's make one step further.
Hint 2.

 Now let $C = 0$. This case is very different from the tree, because now there is one cycle.

When it doesn't matter?
Hint 2a.

 Each vertex $v$ of the cycle may be considered as a root of the tree, induced by all vertices reachable from another vertex of the cycle through $v$ only. So each vertex has it's tree root which can be precomputed. And path between two vertices with the same root can be solved using LCA.

How could we manage remaining difference?
Hint 2b.

 To find path length between vertices from different trees we sum distances to roots and distance between roots. And to find distance between roots there are multiple possibilities. For example we can enumerate vertices $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_k$ of the cycle and compute for every vertex $v_i$ path length to the first one through all previous: $$\ell(v_i) = \begin{cases} 0, & i = 1,\\ \ell(v_{i - 1}) + w(v_{i - 1}, v_i) & i > 1, \end{cases}$$ where $w(u, v)$ is the weight of edge $\{\,u, v\,\}$. Then cycle length is $c = \ell(v_k) + w(v_1, v_k)$. So distance between two roots $v_i$ and $v_j$ is $$\min\{\,|\ell(v_i) - \ell(v_j)|, c - \ell(v_i) + \ell(v_j), \ell(v_i) + c - \ell(v_j)\,\}.$$ Note that we consider three walks two of which are paths, but length of a walk can't be less than length of the shortest path if all edge weights are non-negative.

It doesn't seem to lead us to the general case solution. But we could make this solution more simple and generalizable. Let's just reduce this case to the previous one directly.
Hint 2c.

 For this purpose we can remove edge $e = \{\,v_1, v_k\,\}$ of the cycle. Now let's turn this tree into a rooted tree. Now for a shortest $(u, v)$-path there are two main possibilities: it contains edge $e$ or not. If path doesn't contain the edge $e$ then we find the answer using LOCATION . And if path contains the edge $e$ there are two possible cases depending on the direction on this edge. (One of two subcases still produces a walk which is not a path.) So the length of the shortest $(u, v)$-path is: $$\min\{\,d_T(u, v), d_T(u, v_1) + w(v_1, v_k) + d_T(v_k, v), d_T(u, v_k) + w(v_k, v_1) + d_T(v_1, v)\,\},$$ where $d_T(x, y)$ is the distance between vertices $x$ and $y$ in the tree.

So what about the original problem?
Solution.

 We could do essentially the same for all edges. So the possible scenario is the following: select which edge appears in the walk first and in which direction is it passed, then the next edge and so on. We need to consider up to $1 + 2C + 4C(C - 1) + \ldots + (C + 1)!2^{C + 1} = \mathrm O((C + 1)!2^C)$ cases. However this is $\mathrm O(1)$ since $C$ is constant. (Pokerface)

Isn't that awful? May be, but only in practical sense of the underlying constant, because all formal requirements are satisfied. (Moreover preprocessing takes fair $\mathrm O(n + m)$ of time.) Can we do better?

 Yes, definitely we can do better. Let's find an arbitrary spanning tree and select an arbitrary vertex as the root. Note that $C + 1$ edges of the graph are not included into the tree. Let's call them deleted edges. There are up to $2C + 2$ ends of deleted edges. Apart from distance to root in the tree let's find the distance from every end of a deleted edge to all other vertices in the original graph using Dijkstra algorithm up to $2C + 2$ times. So now it is enough to select just one vertex as intermediate to find length of walk. This vertex is either LCA or an end of a deleted edge. LCA gives us the length of path consisting of tree edges only, and every end of a deleted edge gives us length of a walk which may contain any number of deleted edges. If the shortest path contains no deleted edges then LCA gives us length of this path. If the shortest path contains at least one deleted edge, then every end of every deleted edge of the path gives us the same correct answer.

So what about the running time now?

 We run Dijkstra's algorithm up to $2C + 2$ times and build rooted tree for LCA queries in $\mathrm O(Cm \log n) = \mathrm O(m \log n)$ of time and find path length in $\mathrm O(C) = \mathrm O(1)$ of time.

